# JSON.stringify not working properly in firefox?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, cross-browser, stringify

i'm trying to stringify one object in javascript. In IE, after stringify the values are looks

```
{"jobTypeArray":"[CONTRACT -W2]"}
```

But in Firefox & Chrome values looks

```
{"jobTypeArray":"[\"CONTRACT -W2\"]"}
```

unterminated strings are appended in json.

Here is my Code,

```
var cbJobData = new Object();
var JobTypevalues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selectJobTypeVal.options.length; i++ ) {
    if (selectJobTypeVal.options[i].selected) {
        JobTypevalues.push(selectJobTypeVal.options[i].value);
    }
}
cbJobData.jobTypeArray = JobTypevalues;
```

now i'm going to stringify In this `cbJobdata` , in this place i facing the issue

how to solve this issue. Is json.stringify is IE attribute ?

anybody can help me ?
thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly does the object you are trying to stringify look like?

Comment: How's your object looks like?

Comment: i'm trying to get object look like same as what i getting in I.E, {"jobTypeArray":"[CONTRACT -W2]"}

Comment: @Elayaraja: Yes, we got that, but the question is: What does the object look like _before_ you stringify it?

Comment: Here is my Code, var cbJobData = new Object();  var JobTypevalues = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < selectJobTypeVal.options.length; i++ ){
  if(selectJobTypeVal.options[i].selected){
   JobTypevalues.push(selectJobTypeVal.options[i].value);
  }
 }  cbJobData.jobTypeArray   = JobTypevalues; now i'm going to stringify In this cbJobdata , in this place i facing the issue

Comment: @Elayaraja Please add the content of your latest comment to the question itself.

Comment: @Teemu ok thanks, i will add the comment

Comment: @Elayaraja Are you sure about the outputs, they both look incorrect to me. Also I can't reproduce the issue with IE nor FF.

Comment: @Teemu, yes it is correct. can you show me how you got the output ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nBm3M/. Since `JobTypevalues` is an array, it will *never* be encoded as a *string*, but both of your outputs show it as string. You must be doing something else to the data as well.

Comment: @Elayaraja I'm sorry for the non-working fiddle, please check [the fixed one](http://jsfiddle.net/3PRmS/1/).

Comment: @Elayaraja: If you want the json string to look like the one IE produces, you're actually asking how to mess up your JSON: you're assigning an array to an object property, which (if your post is accurate) is being encoded as a string: `"[whatever]"`, will _not_ be decoded to an array, but a string constant... once again: IE is wrong

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Both outputs are "wrong", you can't get that output from IE nor FF either. Both browsers are working fine with Elayaraja's code, you can check the fiddles of Felix and mine.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is happening by the Browser itsself for security reasons...

You have to stripslashes .. In your  Backend side

Comment: ok. then firefox not supported the stringify ? is it is possible to strip the slashes.